# Retrieve lists from static class method or instance method?

Tags: c#

I’m trying to do a sanity check on getting lists from a database.

Can I use a static method to return a modified list based on a passed parameter?

Also to what extent can I use static methods for returning lists? Can someone point me to some real life examples? Code is all working fine, but recently had an epiphany.

Here is one example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns list of All Projects based on array of enum StatusOfProject
/// </summary>
/// <param name="theStatus"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static IEnumerable<string> List(params Status[] theStatus)
{
    ThrowIf.Argument.IsNull(theStatus);
    var selectedStatus = new List<string>();
    foreach (Status nextStatus in theStatus)
    {
        string theQuery = "select JobNo from ProjectLog where StatusID = " + (int)nextStatus + "  order by JobNo desc";
        using (SqlDataAdapter theSqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(theQuery, TheUtils.OurDBHelpers.GetOurConnectionString()))
        {
            DataSet theDataset = new DataSet();
            theSqlAdapter.Fill(theDataset, "Table");
            DataTable theDataTable = theDataset.Tables["Table"];
            selectedStatus.AddRange(theDataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row["JobNo"].ToString()));
        }
    }

    return selectedStatus;
}
```

Comment: This should be posted in code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you do before using this method and what do you do after?

Comment: I usually loop through these and create objects, such as project information, accounting, etc. that use the values return in the list. I went and posted this on codereview. If you think you should close it here, please do. thx. G

Comment: Even though this query happens to be safe from SQL injection despite the string concatenation (because we're dealing with an `int`), this is still inferior to a proper parameterized query, and I'd wager you will see other, problematic queries that *are* subject to SQL injection if you look further. Use parameters, and avoid lemons like `SqlDataAdapter` and `DataSet` for simple queries in favor of something like Dapper.

Comment: totally agree with the injection comment. also moving the site to EF eventually. Legacy table issues. The code is safe though for Static usage? This kind of method would be used in hundreds of web pages.

Comment: thx @Jeroen for hint of Dapper. Never heard of that. I saw some articles. I'll read up.